# XPath ignore span

Tags: xpath

I have a HTML which contains some tags like below:

```
<div id="SNT">text1</div>
<div id="SNT">text2</div>
<div id="SNT">textbase1<span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text3</span></div>
<div id="SNT">textbase2<span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text4</span></div>
```

how can I get **all** the `text`s included in all `<div>` tags using XPath, ignoring the `span` fields?

i.e.:

```
text1  
text2  
textbase1text3  
textbase2text4
```

Comment: all ids are the same? what xpath implementation are you using?

Comment: yeah, I'm using XPathQuery for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This cannot be specified with a single XPath 1.0 expression.**

**You need to first select all relevant `div` elements:**

```
//div[@id='SNT']
```

**then for each selected node get its string node**:

```
string(.)
```

**In XPath 2.0 this can be specified with a single expression**:

```
//div[@id='SNT]/string(.)
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="div[@id='SNT']">
     <xsl:copy-of select="string()"/>
========    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 1.0 transformation is applied on the following XML document (the provided XML fragment, wrapped into a single top element):**

```
<t>
    <div id="SNT">text1</div>
    <div id="SNT">text2</div>
    <div id="SNT">textbase1<span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text3</span></div>
    <div id="SNT">textbase2<span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text4</span></div>
</t>
```

the relevant `div` elements are selected (matched) and processed by the only specified template, in which the `string(.)` XPath expression is evaluated and its result is copied to the output:

```
    text1
========    

    text2
========    

    textbase1text3
========    

    textbase2text4
========
```

**And for the XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@id='SNT']/string(.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated and the result (four strings) is copied to the output**:

```
text1 text2 textbase1text3 textbase2text4
```

Answer (score 2):

**You could simply use:**

```
//div/text()
```

or

```
div/text()
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will return 2 different string for each `div` with an `span` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link [The lxml.etree Tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html), and search `Using XPath to find text`

For example:

```
from lxml import etree 
html = """
<span class='demo'>
Hi, 
<span>Tom</span>
</span>

tree = etree.HTML(html)
node = tree.xpath('//span[@class="demo"]')[0]
print(node.xpath('string()')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other content in the HTML files, just those `<div>`s inside the usual HTML root elements, the following stylesheet will be sufficient to extract the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you only want the `<div>`s, and only with those particular IDs, use the following code - it also makes sure the linebreaks are like in your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="//div[@id='SNT']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()|text()"/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```