# Java with Xpath caught too much data inside a xml tag

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've a java code like this :

```
expr_divValues = xpathDiv.compile("//div[@class=\"history-entries\"]/div["+(index_historyEntrie+1)+"]/div[@class=\"history-values\"]/div["+(index_historyValue+1)+"]");
result_divValues = expr_divValues.evaluate(doxDiv, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

with this XML data:

```
<div class="history-entry even" data-index="2">
    <span class="history-actor">JEan paul de france</span>
    <span class="history-date" data-time="1676382208618">14 févr. 2023 14:43:28</span>
        <div class="history-values">
            <div class="history-value">
                <span class="history-rank history-rank-first" data-rank="1">1</span>Commentaire de la signature
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

When i use this the result of result_divValues is : 1Commentaire de la signature, the xpath request caught the "1" into the span tag and the only value i need in div Tag.

Tried adding '/text()' at the end of my xpath request, but when i do this, the value is empty.

Anyone for a little help ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968612/xpath-ignore-span

Answer (score 0):

This java code:
`result_divValues = expr_divValues.evaluate(doxDiv, XPathConstants.STRING);`

Is equivalent to using this xpath
`string(//div[@class="history-values"]/div[1])`

Testing on a browser console:

```
$x('string(//div[@class="history-values"]/div[1])');
"
                1Commentaire de la signature
            "
```

Change to `result_divValues = expr_divValues.evaluate(doxDiv, XPathConstants.NODESET);` and pick the proper list element.
This XPath returns 2 nodes:

```
$x('//div[@class="history-values"]/div[1]/text()');
0: #text "
            "​
1: #text "Commentaire de la signature
            "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one.  From [the documentation of the XPath class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html):

> This result of evaluating an expression is converted to an instance of the desired return type. Valid return types are defined in XPathConstants. Conversion to the return type follows XPath conversion rules.

Since you’re converting to a string, the “XPath conversion rules” come from [section 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Function-Calls) of the XPath specification:

> An argument is converted to type string as if by calling the string function.

And [the string() function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) is documented thus:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

The text() node that is first in document order is the whitespace between the `<div class=history-value">` tag and the start of the span tag;  specifically, `"\n                "`.  As the documentation says, only that first text node is evaluated as a string, even though `/text()` matches more than one text child.

A workaround is to examine the text children yourself.  Replace this:

```
result_divValues = expr_divValues.evaluate(doxDiv, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

with this:

```
StringBuilder textContent = new StringBuilder();

NodeList children = (NodeList) expr_divValues.evaluate(doxDiv, XPathConstants.NODESET);
int count = children.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Object child = children.item(i);
    if (child instanceof Text text) {
        textContent.append(text.getData());
    }
}

result_divValues = textContent.toString();
```